# Programmatically Stop Interaction for specific Figure in Jupyter notebook

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

In case there is no need for interaction for a specific matplotlib figure in a Jupyter notebook, how to prevent that programmatically?

Manually that can be done by pressing Ctrl-w or clicking the "Stop Interaction" 
button. I am looking for the API access to the same operation.

Reasons:

- Interactive figures use resources and warnings displayed for too many such figures.
- Closing them manually is not convenient each time the cells are executed
- Without interactive frame figures are more compact.

Answer (score 7):

You can switch between `notebook` mode with interactivity and `inline` mode without such interactivity with:

```
%matplotlib inline
```

and

```
%matplotlib notebook
```

You can do this programmatically in the notebook with:

```
get_ipython().magic('matplotlib notebook')
```

or:

```
get_ipython().magic('matplotlib inline')
```

Comment: No, unfortunately `get_ipython().magic('matplotlib inline')` renders ALL figures in the notebook as inline, not only the next one.

Comment: You need to call `get_ipython().magic('matplotlib notebook')` to switch back to Notebook mode. So just toggle between both modes with the help of the two lines from my answer.

Comment: I understood that. But after switching to inline ALL the figures in the notebook which were in the interactive mode by than become `inline` and loose their interactivity, while I need that only for one specific figure.

Answer (score 1):

The following seems to work, though this is not ideal.

## In cell 1

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)
ax.plot([0,1])
```

## In cell 2

```
plt.close(fig)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can stop interaction using :
*plt.ioff()*

at the end of the plot.